# How to draw a density line for log-log plot in r

Tags: r, plot, distribution

I want to draw a line for the density of our data for analyzing the distribution of nodes (if it's power low or not)
but the line is drawn wrong

this is my code

```
plot(log(nodes2$Var1),log((nodes2$p)),ylim = c(-10,0))
lines(density(log(nodes2$Var1)))
```

this is the result

[image]

Comment: why is it wrong? The second lines plot the y-values must be >= 0 (unless you also log transform the densities)

Comment: As @user20650 correctly comments, there is nothing wrong with the density per se. It is just that the amplitude gets diluted by the limits of the y-axis you specify in your `plot`. You can check for yourself that the function will integrate to 1 on the interval [`min(nodes2$Var1), max(nodes2$Var1)`].

Comment: @user20650 I want to draw a power law line for this data. The line should go through the data not at the top of it